# "TLD skipped" in tomcat logs

Tags: tomcat

I have the following errors in my Tomcat logs. This doesn't affect how the web applications run, but it does fill up the logs. How do I fix this?

```
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Oct 24, 2014 8:53:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was caused by having dependencies on jstl

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and apache stanards taglibs

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Picking one or the other fixed the issue.

Comment: +1 I don't have exactly the same dependencies, but the problem is to have multiple inclusions of the same library

Comment: When I remove this I get an exception when calling my routes in spring instead.